# How to get (total goal value)/(visitor count) in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I've setup an event that fires when a user makes a sale, and a goal based on that event with the same value.

How do I get the value of (total event/goal value)/(total number of new visits) in Google Analytics?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this goal a variable value? As in a purchase for x amount could result in y value but only 1 event triggered?

Comment: @Yhorian, I still don't understand what you're asking, but the goals have different values depending on the price of goods sold, e.g. a purchase of $12.34 was made, that's an event with value of 1234 (because stupid rule that event values are ints)

Comment: That seems like a fairly odd metric.   I'm not sure many people are interested in "average sales per new visitor."  My guess is that you'll have to do the calculation manually.   I doubt that GA has something built in for that.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, I must have explained it wrong. I'm just wondering what revenue per mille I make from new users, e.g. I want to know whether I should buy traffic at $X per 1k, so I want to know the $Y value to compare with to remain profitable

Comment: That makes sense.  You can probably calculate it by hand if it is just a one time thing.  Otherwise Yhorian has a solution with calculated metrics.  I didn't even know about those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do customised formulas in [Calculated Metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en) in Analytics. Try:

```
({{Goal 1 (Goal 1 Value)}} / {{Goal 1 (Goal 1 Completions)}} ) / {{New Users}} / 100
```

This will take the goal value divided by the number of times the goal (and event) was triggered. I also took new users as I wasn't sure what you wanted to qualify as a 'new visitor' in Analytics. Slightly different from your question but should still fit.